# Is possible to insert no value to float?

Tags: c#, types, datatable

I have a datatable, which contains multiple tables of the same type. Till now, most of the columns were of type string, but I changed it to float. However, I had some "empty" rows as a separator of those tables. The value of those columns was "" or string.Empty. Default value is 0.

So, is there a way how to insert "nothing" to a cell with float type?

I tried to insert null, but it seems that datatable does not support nullable types.
Float.parse does not work either - says input string was not in correct format.

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in footer.Table.Columns)
{
    footer[dc] = float.Parse(string.Empty, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you can try this `footer[dc] = default(float);`

Comment: What you mean by `separator of those tables`?

Comment: A `float` is a value type, it always has a value. Why don't you use `Nullable<float>`?

Comment: I mean, like there are two tables inserted in one datatable, and I want them separated by an empty line, so you will see where one table ends and second begins. And Hassan - when I put default(float) there, it will put there zeros

Comment: OK then you should insert blank row `DataTable.NewRow()`; and then add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set non-existent(`null`) value in the `DataTable` you must use the instance of special class `DBNull`.

```
footer[dc] = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: awesome, this one worked :) I will send it for few more tests, but it seems this is exactly what I need!

Comment: @Asheara it show me error cannot convert to system.dbnull to double? ,

Comment: @Asheara i am using entityf,

Comment: Well, it's long time ago, so I can't exactly try it on my code, however, there are several other questions that might help you: [parsing dbnull into double] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202141/parsing-a-dbnull-value-into-double), [cannot cast DBNull into System.Double] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376883/cannot-cast-dbnull-value-to-type-system-double-please-use-a-nullable-type)

From what I've got from it, you either might need to set data to nullable datatype (double?), though if you're having a datatable, i think my problem was that those types weren't supported

Comment: @Dragon you are using different technology. You can ask here [well-formed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question and get qualified assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Float is value type so it cannot be null so its default will be 0.

How ever if you want null then DataType of column should be `Nullable<float>` also written as `float?`.

Comment: when I put Nullable<float> or float? as datatype, it says that Datatable does not support nullable types. But thanks, this answer is helpful, good to know that it always needs to have a value :)

Answer (score 0):

**Convert** doesn't throw an exception when **string** is **null,** but **Parse()** does.
Try to use **double** instead of float because it would be easier to maintain the code and use **Convert.ToDouble** instead of **Parse**