# Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Double'. Please use a nullable type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm having a problem with my code in **object val = method.Invoke line**.
We're using this code to map the mdx fields to our entities (collection). Some data has DBNull values. So I did a research to check if the propertyType is Nullable and implemented the solution. see **Nullable.GetUnderlyingType**. But I'm still encountering this error. **Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Double'. Please use a nullable type.**

```
string propertyKey = entry.Key;
PropertyInfo property = entry.Value;
Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;

propertyType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType) ?? propertyType;

object objectNeedingProperty = objectToPopulate;

MethodInfo method = _dataRowExtFieldMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { propertyType });
object val = method.Invoke(row, new object[] { row, propertyKey });

property.SetValue(objectNeedingProperty, val, null);
```

Comment: Check if the value is DBNull and then handle it appropriate according to your business logic.

Comment: use "Double?" this is the nullable double that is means it accept null value.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know where to put that on my code above

Answer (score 5):

Your object has property of type `double`. Change it to `double?` so you can assign nulls to that property.

Comment: Its helped a lot... (Y) Thankx