# Parsing a DBNULL value into double

Tags: c#, sql, parsing, dbnull, formatexception

I use the following line to convert the `datarow` value into double.

```
double.parse(Convert.ToString(datarow));
```

If the `datarow` is `DBNULL`, I am getting the following exception:

> 'double.Parse(Convert.ToString(data))' threw an exception of type **'System.FormatException'**

How to handle this one without using `tryparse.`

Comment: in your query make sure there are no dbnull. what server are you using?

Comment: see reference http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp, use the method for checking null value with SQL.

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: For empty row i want to get 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another alternative would be to check if the `datarow` is `DBNull`:

```
double d = datarow is DBNull ? 0 : double.Parse(Convert.ToString(datarow));
```

This way, you do not need to check for `DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 3):

`DBNull` can't be cast or parsed to `double` (or `int`, `decimal`, etc), so you have to check if `datarow` is `DBNull` before trying to parse it. It should be a oneliner using the ternary operator:

```
doubleValue = datarow == DBNull.Value ? 0.0 : double.Parse(Convert.ToString(datarow));
```

Comment: probably brackets in different order

Comment: the error was that the result has to be assigned to a variable

Answer (score 3):

I have a bunch of conversion utility methods for such scenarios, in the format similar to this.

```
// tries to convert a general object to double, if a defaultValue is provided, it will silently fall back to it, if not, it will throw exceptions
public static double ToDouble(object obj, double? defaultValue = null) {
  if (obj == null || obj == "" || obj == DBNull.Value) return 0.0;
  try {
    if (obj is string)
      return double.Parse((string)obj);
    return Convert.ToDouble(obj);
  } catch {
    if (defaultValue != null) return defaultValue.Value;
    throw;
  }
}
```

I use this kind of weak-to-strong type conversion utilities mostly when I work with ADO.NET stuff, or other weakly typed interfaces, like reading data from Excel for example.

In my real code I also allow to pass a `CultureInfo` for string conversion, and do some other stuff like normalizing decimal signs, etc. to achieve the best format tolerance.

The general catch clause could be improved of course by catching specific exception types like `FormatException`, but for my needs it works good.