# Add "empty" double value to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I would like to insert data from xml files to sql database. In my xml files are a lot of diffrent rows. But many rows contain empty double values. When i try to add this to my database i get an error.

Here is a short cut from my database insert:

```
   Table<Step> step = Accessor.GetStepTable();
                Step stp = new Step();

                stp.Angle1Actual = stepData.Columns.Contains("Angle1Actual") ? double.Parse(stepData.Rows[index][Array.IndexOf(argsStep, "Angle1Actual")].ToString()) : DBNull.Value;

                step.InsertOnSubmit(stp);
                step.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

The problem is the DBNull is diffrent type

Comment: What is the error message you receive? Are you sure the column allows nulls?

Comment: Is Angle1Actual nullable?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: DBNull is not "null". [It is a type, a class in the framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I found the answer for my problem here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202141/parsing-a-dbnull-value-into-double)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `double.TryParse` instead of `double.Parse`. It returns boolean value if the operation was successfull.

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`DBNull` is not "null". It is a type, a class in the framework.

[Here is an SO question: What is the best way to deal with DBNull's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26809/463206)